# Custom UITableViewCell not showing all properties

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nib

Kind of strange issue here:

I've got a custom nib `UITableViewCell` with a bunch of labels and an imageview. I set the file owner to `UITableViewDelegate`/`Datasource`, I set the custom class in nib file, and I loaded it in to my VC like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BuildCell";
    BuildCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"BuildCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    ...
    return cell
}
```

What is odd is that whenever I set the cellIdentifier to an ID different from what it is in my storyboard, everything loads fine (But this is an issue since then I can't get the segue to work properly). When I set the cell identifiers to match, only some of the properties work correctly. How could this be??

here is the full implementation of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BuildCell";
    BuildCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"BuildCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    Build *build = [self.builds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //cell.school.text = build.school;
    cell.device.text = build.sdk;
    cell.buildType.text = build.config;
    cell.creator.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By %@", build.creator];
    cell.time.text = build.dateCreated;

    switch (build.buildStatus) {
        case kSuccess:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greensmall.png"];
            break;
        case kInProgress:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowsmall.png"];
            break;
        default:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redsmall.png"];
            break;
    }        

    return cell;        
}
```

The only piece that loads properly is the imageView. None of the labels show up. Any ideas?

Comment: check the text to be sure that it is not nil, check the hierarchy of labels and their position and be sure that is not hidden before any other view.

Comment: the cell text is returning null... why would that be?

Comment: have you checked build object, and if your labels are properly connected?